# Calculating Time Differences in Milliseconds

Tags: r, floating-point, division, milliseconds

I want to rowwise calculate the difference of timestamps in milliseconds. The difference (**time_diff**) in the example below **should always be 0.2**, but I am also getting values above and below 0.2.

The problem starts, when *dividing* the milliseconds to seconds and/or adding `numeric` values to a `POSIXct` object.

I assume that it is some floating-point problem, so I tried specifying the amount of *digits.sec and digits, rounding, truncating,* etc... But the problem remains.

Why is that exactly and how to solve this problem?

```
library(dplyr)

options("digits.secs"=10)
options(digits = 10)

id <- 1:12
time <- c("9:34:50" , "9:34:50" , "9:34:51" , "9:34:51" , "9:34:51" , "9:34:51" ,
  "9:34:51" , "9:34:52" , "9:34:52" , "9:34:52" , "9:34:52" , "9:34:52")
ms <- c(600,800,0,200,400,600,800,0,200,400,600,800)

time <- as.POSIXct(time, format="%H:%M:%S", tz="GMT")

# Problem begins here
timeNew <- time + (ms/1000)

timeNewDf <- data.frame(id=id,
                      time=timeNew)

timeNewDf %>% dplyr::mutate(
  time_diff = c(diff(time),0)) %>% 
  dplyr::rowwise()
```

Comment: `timeNewDf %>% mutate(time_diff = round(c(diff(time),0),1))` works for me.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you!! That was almost too easy ;) The result is correct, but the timestamps are still not really. The first two elements of `timeNew` should be **2018-05-30 09:34:50.6 GMT** and **2018-05-30 09:34:50.8 GMT**.. But they are **2018-05-30 09:34:50.5 GMT** and **2018-05-30 09:34:50.7 GMT**. I suppose its 0.5999999 and 0.7999999 miliseconds.

Comment: yeah floating point issues, instead of: `timeNew <- time + (ms/1000)`     use this: `timeNew <- strptime(strftime(time + (ms/1000) , format="%H:%M:%OS"),format="%H:%M:%OS")`

Comment: But this just formats the time, so I see more floating points. But the milliseconds are still 0.599999 instead of 0.6?

Comment: That's true. add an offset. you can experiment with a higher offset and still show till 1 milliseconds digit. added answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POSIXct will approximate to its nearest floating point less than exact time. Add an offset to cater to floating point approximation and show till 1 digit of milliseconds.

```
library(dplyr) 
options("digits.secs"=1)                                        # showing upto 1 digit

# test data
id <- 1:12
time <- c("9:34:50" , "9:34:50" , "9:34:51" , "9:34:51" , "9:34:51" , 
          "9:34:51" , "9:34:51" , "9:34:52" , "9:34:52" , "9:34:52" , "9:34:52" , "9:34:52")
ms <- c(600,800,0,200,400,600,800,0,200,400,600,800)
time <- as.POSIXct(time, format="%H:%M:%S", tz="GMT")

# offset to cater to floating point approximations
timeNew <- time + (ms/1000) + .0001

timeNewDf <- data.frame(id=id, time=timeNew)
timeNewDf %>% mutate(time_diff = round(c(diff(time),0),1))      # rounding to 1 decimal digit

#1   1 2018-05-30 09:34:50.6  0.2 secs
#2   2 2018-05-30 09:34:50.8  0.2 secs
#3   3 2018-05-30 09:34:51.0  0.2 secs
#4   4 2018-05-30 09:34:51.2  0.2 secs
#5   5 2018-05-30 09:34:51.4  0.2 secs
#6   6 2018-05-30 09:34:51.6  0.2 secs
#7   7 2018-05-30 09:34:51.8  0.2 secs
#8   8 2018-05-30 09:34:52.0  0.2 secs
#9   9 2018-05-30 09:34:52.2  0.2 secs
#10 10 2018-05-30 09:34:52.4  0.2 secs
#11 11 2018-05-30 09:34:52.6  0.2 secs
#12 12 2018-05-30 09:34:52.8  0.0 secs
```

Comment: Thats the solution I came up with aswell, but it felt like cheating so I thought there might be a better way to controll decimals etc.. Anyway +1 for all your help! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks. This is a limitation but i wouldn't consider it cheating but more of a forced rounding, as we know the direction to round towards. Do post it here if you find a remedy. it will help many out.